# How to pass java object reference from java side to c++ side?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I want to use JNI to pass java reference to c++ side,then get the object back in java, but I understand java not like c++ that can use reference. Also I want to prevent using external storing variable like Vector to hold the created object. I imagine it has a reference type "MyPointer" like this:

**steps**

1. create object from java side
2. pass reference from java side to c++ side, which "MyPointer" is the object reference which can get back the object at java side
3. get back the object at java side using "MyPointer"

**code**

```
public class MyClass{
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("MyClass");
    }
    public String name;
    public static void backToJavaSide(MyPointer obj){
        MyClass myClass=(MyPointer)obj;
        System.out.println(obj.name);
    }

    public static native void toCppSide(MyPointer obj);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass m1=new MyClass();
        m1.name="abc";
        toCppSide(m1);

        MyClass m2=new MyClass();
        m2.name="def";
        toCppSide(m2);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
abc
def
```

Is there any coding style that can simulate "MyPointer" that can pass java object between java and c++?

Comment: [`jobject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp914)? Also, you might find [jna](https://github.com/twall/jna) easier to use.

Comment: `MyPointer` seems unnecessary; Just use `MyClass`. 

`m1` and `m2` hold references to Java objects that would be seen via JNI as `jobject`, which is a local reference or "handle"  to pass to other JNI functions. Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetObjectClass)?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Just define your native method to accept the object as an argument. It will be received as a `jobject`.

Comment: Do not confuse the technical sense of `reference` in C++ with the more general sense of reference in other contexts! A `jobject` is just a handle that lets you do what needs to be done, mainly calling methods on it, passing it to other methods, perhaps accessing its fields, ...